# HttpMessageNotWritableException when try to use custom MultipartFile implementation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have spring boot with rest controller and this controller must send in response byte[] array with custom header
Response type must be with Content-Type multipart/form-data

My RestController Like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getFile",
    produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<MultipartFile> getFile(@RequestHeader("id") String id) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    var bytes = integrationServices.getBytes(id);
    var multiPartFile = new SignMultiPartFile("name", bytes);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(multiPartFile, headers, HttpStatus.OK)
  
}
```

And I created custom MultiPartFile object

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.*;

public class SignMultiPartFile implements MultipartFile, Serializable {

    private final String fileName;
    private final byte[] bytes;

    public SignMultiPartFile(String fileName, byte[] bytes) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOriginalFilename() {
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return bytes == null || bytes.length == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() {
        return bytes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return  new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void transferTo(File destination) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
            fos.write(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

But when try to get file, I receive error:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class dto.SignMultiPartFile] with preset Content-Type 'multipart/form-data'] \
```

How to fix this issue?

update:
I tried to create class like this but application doen't start with different strange reason? Is exist another way to fix issue with multipart processing?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .indentOutput(true)
            .dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .modulesToInstall(new ParameterNamesModule());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));
        converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```